# la matriz se guarda mal. De alguna manera no estoy viendo el error

Tags: c++

El problema es que no se guarda bien la matriz, no se ponen los datos donde tienen que ir.

Aquí os pongo un conjunto de datos y la matriz que me da:

```
                JUGADOR 1                                                    
Barco de 4:     (1,1) (1,4)                                                            
1 barco de 3:   (2,1) (2,3)                                                 
2 barco de 3:   (3,1) (3,3)                                                 
1 barco de 2:   (4,1) (4,2)                                              
2 barco de 2:   (5,1) (5,2)                                                
3 barco de 2:   (6,1) (6,2)                                                 
1 barco de 1:   (7,1)                                                       
2 barco de 1:   (8,1)                                                        
3 barco de 1:   (9,1)                                                        
4 barco de 1:   (10,1)                                                      

                JUGADOR 2
Barco de 4:     (10,1) (10,4)   
1 barco de 3:   (9,1) (9,3)
2 barco de 3:   (8,1) (8,3)
1 barco de 2:   (7,1) (7,2) 
2 barco de 2:   (6,1) (6,2)
3 barco de 2:   (5,1) (5,2)
1 barco de 1:   (4,1)
2 barco de 1:   (3,1)
3 barco de 1:   (2,1)
4 barco de 1:   (1,1)


1      10      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0          
0      9      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0          
0      8      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0          
0      7      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0         
0      6      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0         
0      5      5      0      0      0      0      0      0      0           
0      4      4      0      0      0      0      0      0      0          
0      3      3      3      0      0      0      0      0      0           
0      2      2      2      0      0      0      0      0      5           
5      1      1      1      2      4      0      0      0      3          


10      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      9
9      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      8
8      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      7
7      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6
6      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      5
5      5      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      4
4      4      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      3
3      3      3      0      0      0      0      0      0      2
2      2      2      0      0      0      0      0      5      1
1      1      1      2      4      0      0      0      3      3
```

Como veis, a menos que yo sea muy tonto y me esté equivocando en los datos, la matriz no los guarda como debería.

```
int mat[9][9][1], i, j, i1, j1, cnt2;
    for (int z = 0; z <= 1; z++) {
        cnt2 = 1;
        cout << "JUGADOR " << z + 1 << "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { //Inicializar la matriz a 0
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                mat[i][j][z] = 0;
            }
        }
        do { //Poner el barco de 4
            do {
                cout << "\nIntroduce la 1 coordenada del barco de 4: "; cin >> i; cin >> j;
                cout << "\nIntroduce la 2 coordenada del barco de 4: "; cin >> i1; cin >> j1;
            } while (unoadiez(i) != true || unoadiez(j) != true || unoadiez(i1) != true || unoadiez(j1) != true);
        } while (comp4(i, j, i1, j1, 3) != true);
        if (i == i1) {
            if (j < j1) {
                for (int k = j - 1; k < j1; k++) {
                    mat[i - 1][k][z] = cnt2;
                }
            }
            else {
                for (int k = j - 1; k > j1; k--) {
                    mat[i - 1][k][z] = cnt2;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (i < i1) {
                for (int k = i - 1; k < i1; k++) {
                    mat[k][j - 1][z] = cnt2;
                }
            }
            else {
                for (int k = i - 1; k > i1; k--) {
                    mat[k][j - 1][z] = cnt2;
                }
            }
        }
        cnt2++;
        for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= 2; cnt++) {
            do { //Poner los barcos de 3
                do {
                    cout << "\nIntroduce la primera coordenada del " << cnt << " barco de 3: "; cin >> i; cin >> j;
                    cout << "\nIntroduce la segunda coordenada del " << cnt << " barco de 3: "; cin >> i1; cin >> j1;
                } while (unoadiez(i) != true || unoadiez(j) != true || unoadiez(i1) != true || unoadiez(j1) != true);
            } while (comp4(i, j, i1, j1, 2) != true);
            if (i == i1) {
                if (j < j1) {
                    for (int k = j - 1; k < j1; k++) {
                        mat[i - 1][k][z] = cnt2;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    for (int k = j - 1; k > j1; k--) {
                        mat[i - 1][k][z] = cnt2;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if (i < i1) {
                    for (int k = i - 1; k < i1; k++) {
                        mat[k][j - 1][z] = cnt2;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    for (int k = i - 1; k > i1; k--) {
                        mat[k][j - 1][z] = cnt2;
                    }
                }
            }
            cnt2++;
        }
        for (int cnt1 = 1; cnt1 <= 3; cnt1++) {
            do { //Poner los barcos de 2
                do {
                    cout << "\nIntroduce la primera coordenada del " << cnt1 << " barco de 2: "; cin >> i; cin >> j;
                    cout << "\nIntroduce la segunda coordenada del " << cnt1 << " barco de 2: "; cin >> i1; cin >> j1;
                } while (unoadiez(i) != true || unoadiez(j) != true || unoadiez(i1) != true || unoadiez(j1) != true);
            } while (comp4(i, j, i1, j1, 1) != true);
            if (i == i1) {
                if (j < j1) {
                    for (int k = j - 1; k < j1; k++) {
                        mat[i - 1][k][z] = cnt2;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    for (int k = j - 1; k > j1; k--) {
                        mat[i - 1][k][z] = cnt2;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if (i < i1) {
                    for (int k = i - 1; k < i1; k++) {
                        mat[k][j - 1][z] = cnt2;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    for (int k = i - 1; k > i1; k--) {
                        mat[k][j - 1][z] = cnt2;
                    }
                }
            }
            cnt2++;
        }
        for (int cnt1 = 1; cnt1 <= 4; cnt1++) {   //Poner los barcos de 1
            do {
                cout << "\nIntroduce la posicion del " << cnt1 << " barco de 1: "; cin >> i; cin >> j;
            } while (unoadiez(i) != true || unoadiez(j) != true);
            mat[i - 1][j - 1][z] = cnt2;
            cnt2++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: en los do anidados veo que te entran las coordenadas pero que haces con ellas??

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, consulta [ask] y el [tour] para que sepas cómo funciona este portal. Además así ganarás tu primera medalla. Tienes que añadir más información... es poco probable que alguien se coja tu código e intente adivinar tus intenciones...

Comment: Esas funciones son para comprobar que las coordenadas son correctas, Alex Rivas, es decir, que en los barcos de 4 haya 4 espacios, en los de 3, 3... Y comprueban que se haya puesto en vertical o horizontal

Comment: do { //Poner el barco de 4
        do {
            cout << "\nIntroduce la 1 coordenada del barco de 4: "; cin >> i; cin >> j;
            cout << "\nIntroduce la 2 coordenada del barco de 4: "; cin >> i1; cin >> j1;
        } while (unoadiez(i) != true || unoadiez(j) != true || unoadiez(i1) != true || unoadiez(j1) != true);
    } while (comp4(i, j, i1, j1, 3) != true);

esto exactamente que hace pues no veo que guardes ninguno de estos datos en caso de que sean correctos...no se si estoy pasando algo x alto

Comment: Eso solo son funciones de control, es decir, que si no dan true no se sale del bucle y vuelve a pedir los datos. En unoadiez se comprueba que el número esté entre 1 y 10  mientras que comp4 comprueba que tenga una diferencia correcta (4 en caso de los barcos de 4, 3 en caso de los barcos de 3...) 'bool comp4(int i, int j, int i1, int j1, int a) {
 if (i == i1 && (j1 - j == a || j - j1 == a)) {
  return true;
 }
 if (j == j1 && (i1 - i == a || i - i1 == a)) {
  return true;
 }
 cout << "\nNo has introducido unas coordenadas v�lidas";
 return false;
}'   @AlexRivas

Comment: lo que te qeria decir era en q parte del codigo guardas la informacion del array?? es lo q no veo en tu codigo

Comment: @AlexRivas, no estoy muy seguro de a que te refieres. Soy un estudiante de ingeniería informática muy principiante entonces probablemente sea ignorancia mía, en cualquier caso, es en ese fragmento de texto dónde se guardan los datos en el array, no hay ningún otro sitio donde se guarde la matriz. Destaco que este es un programa de muy bajo nivel y bastante patético dado que no tengo nivel para hacer nada mucho más elaborado.